# Pose/rest pose not working on Models

Tags: pose-mode

So I have a model that I'm posing I get it all set up and i copy it (selecting everything in object mode into my scene) but it pastes over back into T pose or the original pose. The same thing if i try to render it the render comes out with T pose I have tried ctrl a in pose mode and "apply pose as rest pose" but when i click it it just resets to T pose. I have tried all the options when I ctrl A and nothing works.

Comment: Did you ever insert a keyframe with the pose you created?

Comment: How do I do that ? I'm super new I just have the basics down.

Comment: Ah, so my first guess was right...
Okay, i will try to write an Answer

Answer (score 0):

Keyframes in Blender are a key concept not just in animation, but also when working with poses. When you pose a character or object in Blender, it won't retain that pose by default. It may snap back to its rest pose whenever you render or perform certain actions, like copying and pasting or move along the timeline. To make your posed character or object stick to its pose, you need to create keyframes.

Think of keyframes as snapshots of an object's properties (like position, rotation, or scale) at specific points in time. By setting keyframes at different moments and adjusting the properties between them, you can create animations.

But you also need to create a keyframe of your pose for just a single frame without an animation. There needs to be a keyframe to store the information of how your pose is `posed`.

To insert a keyframe, first pose your model to your liking, then press the `I` key (for `Insert Keyframe`). A menu will appear to insert a keyframe for `location`, `rotation` or `scale` as well as several combinations of them, as you may affect your pose by moving (location), rotating or scaling of your rigs bones. If you are only posing for a still image, it should always be okay to insert a keyframe for `location, rotation & scale`, which is: Everything you may have possibly changed. If you are doing animation, you should select just the the things you actually modified, or it will affect your animation in unexpected ways.
Now if you crated a keyframe of your pose, your model will keep its pose when you are rendering.

Comment: Hi so this initially worked got the pose rendered it fine then I moved his head did the same thing now when i render his heads gone?

Comment: Do I select the whole model, the rig, just the part I've moved or all of them ?

Comment: Now I cant change the pose no matter what i select on key frames... it just stays the same do I have to delete the old keyframe ?

Comment: maybe you where not in pose made anymore?